# "Failure from drain_fd: No error" Tor Windows

Tags: windows

What does it mean? This is the latest version of the Tor expert bundle. The error appears regularly on the cmd terminal window.

Comment: Looks like ticket [#21540](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/21540). Didn't look into it very closely but looks like you run out of file descriptors (FD) when too many connections are opened.

Comment: (sigh) Guess I shoulda known not to rely on a consumer version of Windows :(

Comment: Can anyone recommend a Windows patch...at least until I can get a Debian or BSD box going?

Comment: There appears to be a [fix](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/commit/?id=44514058b96440eaa1b364b915860ae372207ca6) in the master branch. You could build master yourself or cherry pick the commit. If you're lucky the fix will have been backported when the next stable release happens. (in a month or so)

Answer (score 1):

As of [Tor 0.3.1.1-alpha](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/tor-0312-alpha-out-notes-about-0311-alpha) a fix is now included.

From the changelog:

> Resolve "Failure from drain_fd: No error" warnings on Windows relays. Fixes bug [21540](https://bugs.torproject.org/21540); bugfix on 0.2.6.3-alpha.

Comment: Thanks for the note....I just gave up and built a Linux relay. Everything works.